# How can i change the StatelessWidget class into setState so that my icons refresh when clicked?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, setstate

I am having trouble changing the class so that my icons without reloading the app will change. The problem is that I don't know how to properly change the StateWidget class to setState, because without it I don't know how my application will work

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


List done = [Icons.check_box];

class SecondRoute extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  title: const Text('your list'),
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 1,//Normal textInputField will be displayed
                  maxLines: 5,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () { done [0] = Icons.question_mark; },
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                highlightColor: Colors.amberAccent, //<-- SEE HERE
                iconSize: 100,
                icon: Icon(
                  done[0],
                ),
              )
            ],
         ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I tried to change a whole second route but I don't know how to do it without destroying a whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert it to `StatefulWidget` to call `setState`
More about [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)

```dart
class SecondRoute extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondRoute({super.key});

  @override
  State<SecondRoute> createState() => _SecondRouteState();
}

class _SecondRouteState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  List done = [Icons.check_box];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
      body: Center(
        child: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: AppBar(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                  title: const Text('your list'),
                ),
              ),
              const Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                  minLines: 1, //Normal textInputField will be displayed
                  maxLines: 5,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  done[0] = Icons.question_mark;
                  setState(() {});
                },
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                highlightColor: Colors.amberAccent, //<-- SEE HERE
                iconSize: 100,
                icon: Icon(
                  done[0],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```